# Error processing gps file in R script

Tags: r, gps

Newbie R question:  I have been trying to test the R script posted in [FlowingData](http://flowingdata.com/2014/02/05/where-people-run/), but the script spit out the following error:

Error: XML content does not seem to be XML: 'NA'

I am running R on my windows box, with the .gpx files in the same directory as the script. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can we have a look at your xml file ?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you ever found the answer to this or not, but the XML error relates to the fact that R does not know where your .gpx files are.  While the FlowingData script indicates that the script will work if the .gpx files are in the same folder as your saved R script copy/pasted from FlowingData, that is not true.  You must also set your working directory to this path as well, then R will see your .gpx files.  If you FlowingData R script file and .gpx files are in: C:\Users\leon\Documents\R  then add this line under the library(plotKML) line to set your working directory:  setwd("C:\\Users\\leon\\Documents\\R")

Another word of note, make sure you only use the RunKeeper gpx files for a fairly small geographic area or the plotted data will be insanely small.